# Prevent reset of Redux State on React Native Fast Refresh (expo cli)

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to understand how to combine react native fast refresh with redux. I have cloned the following project: https://github.com/amandeepmittal/rnReduxhooks

When changing code in the view `ViewNotes.js` fast refresh works fine. But when changing code in the reducer `notesApp.js` **fast refresh resets the redux state**.

How can I prevent that?

Is there a tutorial for react native and redux similar to the ones for react and redux? (https://duske.me/setting-up-hot-module-replacement-with-create-react-app-and-redux/)

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by saving the state on each change into a variable `mycache` defined in a new file `statecache.ts`. When creating the store I hydrate the state from this variable.

Thus the state is only resetted when I edit `statecache.ts` but not when I edit reducers / views.

https://github.com/denniske/rnReduxhooks/commit/c2a0279927bf7c32b5f2507905ad146cff742770

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!